# Error: C compiler "C:/Program Files..." is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, compiler-errors, carla

I am working to install Carla from source and already installed the unreal engine. When i try to build the CARLA using the **make Python API** command, i am getting an error as

> C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
> Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
> is not able to compile a simple test program

Herewith attaching the full lines from the x64 Native Tools command prompt

```
d:\Test\resimulation2>make PythonAPI
-[Setup]: [Batch params]: --boost-toolset msvc-14.2 --all
-[Setup]: Asynchronous jobs:  8
-[Setup]: Boost toolset:      msvc-14.2
-[Setup]: Install directory:  "d:\Test\resimulation2\Build\"
-[Setup]: Creating "d:\Test\resimulation2\Build\" folder...
-[Setup]: Installing zlib...
    -[install_zlib]: [Batch params]: --build-dir "d:\Test\resimulation2\Build\"
    -[install_zlib]: Retrieving zlib.
    -[install_zlib]: Extracting zlib from "zlib-1.2.13.zip".
    -[install_zlib]: Removing "zlib-1.2.13.zip"
    -[install_zlib]: Creating "d:\Test\resimulation2\Build\zlib-source\build"
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30146.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: D:/Test/resimulation2/Build/zlib-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):nmake -f Makefile /nologo cmTC_2e0d7\fast &&   C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_2e0d7.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_2e0d7.dir\build
    Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
    konnte nicht gefunden werden.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Program' : return code '0x1'
    Stop.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Test/resimulation2/Build/zlib-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Test/resimulation2/Build/zlib-source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

    -[install_zlib]: [CMAKE ERROR] An error ocurred while executing cmake command.
    -[install_zlib]: [CMAKE ERROR] Possible causes:
    -[install_zlib]:                - Make sure "CMake" is installed.
    -[install_zlib]:                - Make sure it is available on your Windows "path".
    -[install_zlib]:                - Make sure you have cmake 3.12.4 or higher installed.
    -[install_zlib]: Exiting with error...

-[Setup]:
   Ok, and error ocurred, don't panic!
   We have different platforms where you can find some help :)

   - Make sure you have read the documentation:
       http://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_to_build_on_windows/

   - If the problem persists, you can ask on our Github's "Building on Windows" issue:
       https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/issues/21

   - Or just use our Discord channel!
       We'll be glad to help you there :)
       https://discord.gg/42KJdRj
make: *** [setup] Fehler 1
```

What may be the issue ?

Comment: looks like whatever you're trying to build can't handle spaces in file names properly. Looks like having make on a path with spaces is the main problem

Comment: The `nmake` build line is incorrectly quoted.

Comment: Spaces in the file path, probably a bad idea to install GnuWin in Program Files

Comment: Can you share which file path has space issue ? The visual studio (C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio) or the root folder ?

Comment: @RonyShaji It seems to be the path to make `C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe`.

Comment: Visual Studio uses spaces in filenames all the time, so just works. Also kind of cocky to blame the compiler, when it is the install test script that fails...

Comment: @john found the problem and it does appear to be spaces. It's not related to Visual Studio but calling GNU `make` for some reason on this line in addition to using `nmake`: `Run Build Command(s):nmake -f Makefile /nologo cmTC_2e0d7\fast &&   C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_2e0d7.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_2e0d7.dir\build`

Comment: @drescherjm Any solution to the issue ? Does reinstaling or rebooting helps ?

Comment: ***Does reinstaling or rebooting helps ?*** Neither are likely to help. I am unsure why GNU make is involved in the CMake part of the build however my main use of CMake is  in `c++` code alone without using python.

Comment: As a workaround you could install the tools that are in `C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin`  (not sure what you installed there) in a location that does not have a space in any part of the path (perhaps `c:\GnuWin32\bin`) and adjust your system PATH variable to point to the new location. That may be where python is or may have been installed with python.

Comment: @drescherjm Now I uninstalled the make from the older directory (C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin) and installed it in (C:\windows\GnuWin32\bin). Also added it to the path variable. But now the problem is that the make is not detecting....when i run make -v  in the cmd, it says the command not found...!!

Comment: Is make.exe in that folder: `C:\windows\GnuWin32\bin` if it is you may need to check your PATH recheck variable to make sure it has `C:\windows\GnuWin32\bin` and if it does try logging out then back in. Modifying environment variables in the OS will not propagate to running child processes.

Comment: @drescherjm  I donno what is happening, but something is keep on adding the old make  folder path to the PATH Variable. I deleted it and again it is coming automatically...plz check images for reference.  https://ibb.co/VxhptHj
https://ibb.co/SfdyDgz
https://ibb.co/kMzdT8T

Comment: I can't access the links at work. If there is a CMakeCache.txt move it out of the current folder. This is just a guess.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks mate. Your solution of installing in another folder worked. So it seems it was the issue of the space.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and sharing it here. Thought someone needs it.

Check for any spaces in the installation folder of the gnuwin make.

For eg: The gnuwin make was first installed in the directory C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin and since there is a space between Program and files, the error came.

As a work around, install the gnuwin make in a directory without spaces.